# How to use hasOwnProperty and retrive its value in a nested JSON

Tags: jquery

```
{
    "testPositionSeq": "12345",
    "test": {
        "testSeq": "45678",
        "name": "Testing 1",
        "testProgram": {
            "testProgramSeq": "4567",
            "name": "test25",
            "spreadMethod": null,
            "ul": false,
            "ps": "2",
            "somestatus": "distributed"
        }
    }
}
```

I have a JSON show above .
 I need to chect if it has got the somestatus property , if yes then retrive its value

I have tried as following , but its not working

```
if (test.hasOwnProperty('test.testProgram.somestatus')) { 
 alert('yes')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/48809/

Comment: I would try this https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/48821/

Comment: Thank you , hw can i get the value ?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/48829/

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the string and use `reduce` to loop thru the array. This will return an empty object if not found. Will return the value if found.

```js
let obj = {
  "testPositionSeq": "12345",
  "test": {
    "testSeq": "45678",
    "name": "Testing 1",
    "testProgram": {
      "testProgramSeq": "4567",
      "name": "test25",
      "spreadMethod": null,
      "ul": false,
      "ps": "2",
      "somestatus": "distributed"
    }
  }
};

let key = 'test.testProgram.somestatus';
let result = key.split('.').reduce((c, v) => {
  if (c.hasOwnProperty(v)) return c[v];
  else return {};
}, obj);

console.log(result);
```

**You can make it shorter as:**

```
let result = key.split('.').reduce((c,v)=>  c[v] || {},obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
  if(test.testProgram.somestatus){
     alert('yes');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
 var test = {
            "testPositionSeq": "12345",
            "test": {
                "testSeq": "45678",
                "name": "Testing 1",
                "testProgram": {
                    "testProgramSeq": "4567",
                    "name": "test25",
                    "spreadMethod": null,
                    "ul": false,
                    "ps": "2",
                    "somestatus": "distributed"
                }
            }
        };

        if (test.test.testProgram.hasOwnProperty('somestatus')) {
            alert('yes');
            var value = test.test.testProgram.somestatus;
        }
```

only reason being you must start with **test** as the variable itself is name as test, then comes the property **test** and then **testprogram** property where you need to check if **somestatus** property exists